# How to run fragment inside Android screen with tabs?

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a screen with two tabs and for each tab I'm trying to run different fragment with different layout.

I currently have the following:

- MainFragmentActivity - activitiy which extends FragmentActivity
- mainFraggment_screen - XML for MaiFragmentActivity
- Fragment1 - activity when user clicks on Tab1
- fragmnet1_screen - XML for that
- Fragment2 - activity when user clicks on Tab2
- fragment2_screen - XML for that

Everything is working but the problem is that when application starts there in just an empty screen with tabs Tab1 and Tab2. Fragment of certain activity only appears when user clicks on Tab2 for example. And when he clicks back on Tab1, fragment for Tab1 appears normally.

I would like for that fragment of Tab1 to start immediately when application starts but I don't know how to accomplish that.

Any ideas? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is after adding all the tabs, this needs to be done in onCreate():

```
TabInfo activeTab = (TabInfo) this.hashMapTab.get("Tab1");
    FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    activeTab.fragment = Fragment.instantiate(this,activeTab.className.getName(), activeTab.args);
    ft.add(R.id.tab1, activeTab.fragment, activeTab.tag);
    ft.attach(activeTab.fragment);
    lastTab = activeTab;
    ft.commit();
```

hashMapTab is a hash map of TabInfo of all tabs. TabInfo is a container of all Tab data, like class name and tag of the tab.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Fragment transaction issues. but I would need to see the code of the MainActivity.

I am assuming you are using the FragmentTransactions.add and FragmentTransaction.replace to move them in and out.

Comment: Hm ... I'm doing it with fragment.attach, fragment.detach and then fragment.commit. So, after every click on tab, app checks if it's the new tab selected. If it is new tab selected, old fragment is removed and new one is attached. If it's a old tab selected, nothing happens. Everything works when user clicks on tab but I don't like that that empty screen when app starts.

Comment: tabInfo.fragment = this.getSupportFragmentManager()findFragmentByTag("Tab1"); 
FragmentTransaction fragment = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
fragment.attach(tabInfo.fragment); 
fragment.commit();

Comment: O.K. then it might be that youre just not setting the current tab on load? TabHost.setCurrentTab(mCurrentTab);

Comment: That sets the tab but still not the content of that tab. That's weird. It only marks the tab like it's pressed but still user needs to press tab again to show content.

Comment: Then its how you decide what tab content to show. In other words, you are likely just working off user information rather than the tabhost info. tabhost.getCurrentTab(). Its either a timing issue of when you make decisions to show content or its you are working off of "if the user does this attach this fragment" rather than "If the current tab is this attach this fragment". Once again, without seeing the mainactivity Im just guessing.